# Adding a range of values in to a List using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, matrix

I have a `List<List<double>> val` with 2000 lists and 2000 elements in each list (you can imagine it as 2000 X 2000 matrix). I have two double values say x and y. I need to select all the elements in `List<List<double>> val` which fall between the range x and y. Can I do this using a single statement in C# using LinQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val.SelectMany(a => a).Where(a => a < y && a > x)
```

[`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) flattens your lists and then the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) filters it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
val.Where((l, i) => i < y && i > x)
   .Select(l => l.Where((v, i) => i < y && i > x))
```

The difference to Davids answer is, that here the "x/y-coordinate of the matrix" is filtered by using the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) overload which also supplies the elements index.

With the following matrix:

> [11, 12, 13, 14]
>     [21, 22, 23, 24]
>     [31, 32, 33, 34]
>     [41, 42, 43, 44]

and `x = 0` and `y = 3` you would get the following matrix as a result:

> [22, 23]
>     [32, 33]

See example [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FUw1vq).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
var query = from z in val.SelectMany(i=> i)
            where z > x && x < y
            select z;
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
List<double> abc = (from listA in matrix from theVal in listA where (theVal > 5 && theVal < 6) select theVal).ToList();
```

Comment: state your reason for -1